# Sending buffer on UART with DMA

Tags: arm, dma

First I initialize DMA

```
void DMA_Init(void)
{
    //enable clock for DMAMUX and DMA
    SIM_SCGC6 |= SIM_SCGC6_DMAMUX0_MASK;
    SIM_SCGC7 |= SIM_SCGC7_DMA_MASK;

    //enable channel 0 and set the source - 3 = UART0 Transmit ($3.3.9.1 Table 3-26)
    DMAMUX0_CHCFG0 |= DMAMUX_CHCFG_ENBL_MASK | DMAMUX_CHCFG_SOURCE(3);

    //enable request signal for channel 0
    DMA_ERQ = DMA_ERQ_ERQ0_MASK;

    //set memory address for source and destination
    DMA_TCD0_SADDR = (uint32_t)&log_buffer_data_1;  //global scope buffer
    DMA_TCD0_DADDR = (uint32_t)&UART0_D;

    //set an offset 
    //increment the address by one, after each cycle
    DMA_TCD0_SOFF = 1;
    DMA_TCD0_DOFF = 0;

    //set data transfer size - 0 = byte
    DMA_TCD0_ATTR = DMA_ATTR_SSIZE(0) | DMA_ATTR_DSIZE(0);

    //number of bytes to be transfered in each service request
    //minor byte transfer count
    DMA_TCD0_NBYTES_MLNO = glob_data_chank;

    //current major iteration count (a single iteration)
    //current major iteration count
    DMA_TCD0_CITER_ELINKNO = DMA_CITER_ELINKNO_CITER(1);
    //starting major iteration count
    DMA_TCD0_BITER_ELINKNO = DMA_BITER_ELINKNO_BITER(1);

    DMA_TCD0_SLAST = 0;   //???
    DMA_TCD0_DLASTSGA = 0; //???

    //setup control and status register
    //should be inactive before write
    DMA_TCD0_CSR = 0;

    //interrupt when tx/rx buffer is full. stop DMA on single transfer.
    DMA_TCD0_CSR = DMA_CSR_INTMAJOR_MASK | DMA_CSR_DREQ_MASK;
}
```

At this point I have some questions

1. Do I need the interrupt? I can poll the done flag

   while (DMA_TCD0_CSR & DMA_CSR_DONE_MASK)
2. How do I start a new transaction? Is START flag enough?

   DMA_TCD0_CSR |= DMA_CSR_START_MASK;

Right now my send fuction looks like this

```
void DMA_Start(uint8_t *data, uint32_t pakage_size)
{
    while ((DMA_TCD0_CSR & DMA_CSR_DONE_MASK) == 0);

    //size to be transferred - reload each request
    DMA_TCD0_NBYTES_MLNO = pakage_size;

    //set memory address for source and destination - reload each request?
    DMA_TCD0_SADDR = (uint32_t)&data;
    //DMA_TCD0_DADDR = (uint32_t)&UART0_D;

    //current major iteration count - reload each request?
    DMA_TCD0_CITER_ELINKNO = DMA_CITER_ELINKNO_CITER(1);
    //starting major iteration count
    DMA_TCD0_BITER_ELINKNO = DMA_BITER_ELINKNO_BITER(1);

    //enable auto disable request feature
    DMA_TCD0_CSR |= DMA_CSR_DREQ_MASK;
    //enable major interrupt
    DMA_TCD0_CSR |= DMA_CSR_INTMAJOR_MASK;

    //re-enable channel request
    DMA_SERQ = DMA_SERQ_SERQ(0);

    DMA_TCD0_CSR |= DMA_CSR_START_MASK;
}
```

And I don't know if it's good for send.

Comment: The DMA controller is not 'arm' specific, but IP of the vendor.  For instance, NXP has IMX cpus and STM line by ST.  You should at least give some particulars of the device so we can know the particular DMA controller.  There is not much that is arm specific to that.  So add an IMX tag [tag:imx6], [tag:imx7], [tag:imx8]...  and give a few more details of the particular software stack (linux, bare metal, etc.)

Comment: For some IMX DMA peripherals there is an assembly language for the DMA controller.  The controller is preloaded with some peripheral support and you don't use the DMA controller directly.  For others, you need to load some code to the DMA controller; it is like a mini-cpu with it's own RISC CPU that is memory movement focused but can do simple calcluations on data (CRC offload, etc).  Eg: [IMX SDMA](https://lore.kernel.org/all/1376985873-25776-3-git-send-email-s.hauer@pengutronix.de/) and [sdma-firmware](https://git.pengutronix.de/cgit/imx/sdma-firmware/tree/).  NXP is not helpful on details.

Comment: 1. What the point of using DMA if you are going to poll? These two are contradictory to each other.

Comment: It's a NXP Kinetis series K10P144M120SF3. Generally DMA work principle will be the same for any CPU. It can differ in some aspects but most of the registers the same like source and destination address, major and minor counters etc. Details I want to know like to use the  interrupt or to poll the done flag - it'll be the same for all.

Comment: I'm going to poll the end of the transfer. I can't send a new packet until the previous is completed anyway. By the time it sends I'm going to perform some time consuming operation (read next package 4Kb from SPI memory) in a loop.